# Distribute numbers to two "containers" and minimize their difference of sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose there are n numbers let says we have the following 4 numbers 15,20,10,25

**There are two container A and B and my job is to distribute numbers to them so that the sum of the number in each container have the least difference.**

In the above example, A should have 15+20 and B should have 10+ 25. So difference = 0.

I think of a method. It seems to work but I don't know why.

> Sort the number list in descending order first. In each round, take the maximum number out
>   and put to the container have less sum.

Btw, is it can be solved by DP? 
THX

Comment: See: [Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). Also, [this](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/issue.aspx?id=3278&y=0&no=&content=true&page=4&css=print) is a great read.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292162/partition-problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [divide list in two parts that their sum closest to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479479/divide-list-in-two-parts-that-their-sum-closest-to-each-other)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In fact, **your method doesn't always work**. Think about that `2,4,4,5,5`.The result by your method will be `(5,4,2)(5,4)`, while the best answer is `(5,5)(4,4,2)`.
2. Yes, it **can** be solved by **Dynamical Programming**.Here are some useful link:

   > Tutorial and Code: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~wdtseng/icpc/notes/dp3.pdf
   >   A practice: http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/ (then click `Balanced Partition`)
3. What's more, please note that if the scale of problem is damn large (like you have 5 million numbers etc.), you won't want to use DP which needs a too huge matrix. If this is the case, you want to use a kind of **Monte Carlo** Algorithm:

   > 1. divide n numbers into two groups randomly (or use your method at this step if you like);
   > 2. choose one number from each group,
   >      if (to swap these two number decrease the difference of sum) swap them;
   > 3. repeat step 2 until "no swap occurred for a long time".

   You don't want to expect this method could always work out with the best answer, but it is the only way I know to solve this problem at **very large scale** within reasonable time and memory.

Comment: could you elaborate a little as i am really impatient to read it entirely and i see "T[x] will be true if and only if there is a subset of the numbers that has sum x" in the starting of paper. i think the basic idea is of dp is also a knapsack filling problem.